# Google apps script to find a string and change the column background color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have the results of a google form (a google spreadsheet). I would like to write an app script to check each column for a string "YES." If the column has that string, then I would like to change the background color of that column (or one cell in that column) green. The number of columns will vary each time the form is sent so it would need to check all columns used *(Sorry, I mean I send out a similar form each time and want to use the same script on each one, except that each time the form is used it can come back with a different number of columns-responses - thanks corn3lius)*. Can this be done in a google form response spreadsheet? Here is the code I am playing with. (updated code with Cooper's input)

```
function colchk(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var resp = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var n=0;n<resp.length;n++)
{ 
for(var p=0;p<resp[n].length;p++)
{
if(resp[n][p].toString().match(/^YES/)){ ss.getRange(n+1,p+1).setBackground('#00ff00')}}};
}    
//this code works...Thanks Cooper!
```

Comment: what do you mean "... each time the form is sent"? do you mean a response is entered into the spreadsheet?

Comment: answer: yes. show us coding issues to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I send out a similar form each time and want to use the same script on each one, except that each time the form is used it can come back with a different number of columns-responses - thanks corn3lius

Comment: You could use conditional formatting.

Comment: I would be happy to use conditional formatting, but not quite sure what that would look like. Thanks.

Comment: Just look at the format menu for conditional formatting.  It has an easy to use dialog.

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post, but I'd like to leave an easier solution here for any future visitors:

```js
function colorYesCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var yesFinder = sheet.createTextFinder("YES");
  var yesCells = yesFinder.findAll();
  
  yesCells.forEach(function(cell){
    cell.setBackground('#00ff00');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(resp[n][0].toString().match(/^YES/){ ss.getRange(n+1,1).setBackground('#00ff00') };
```

Perhap's something like this:

```
function colchk(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var resp = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var n=0;n<resp.length;++n)
{ 
  for(var p=0;p<resp[n].length;p++)
  {
    if(resp[n][p].toString().match(/^YES/){ ss.getRange(n+1,p+1).setBackground('#00ff00') };
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Cooper. That works. I made an attempt to add something to loop through the columns but it is not working. The code above still only works for the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I write here :

```
for(var n=0;n<resp.length;++n)
```

should be :

```
for(var n=0;n<resp.length;n++)
```

++n --> n++

typing too fast ?

Comment: I've never actually used the ++n in a loop but I believe it will increment the index before the loop starts.

Comment: This won't change a thing because the third argument of `for()` is only evaluated after each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

based off @coopers code- small edits

```js
function colchk(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var resp = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var n=0;n<resp.length;n++)
{ 
  for(var p=0;p<resp[n].length;p++)
  {
    if(resp[n][p].toString().match(/^YES/)) { 
      ss.getRange(n+1,p+1).setBackground('#00ff00') };
  }
}};
```